# toLocaleString R$ brasileiro

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma dúvida simples sobre o `toLocaleString`, eu não conhecia esse prototype e fui testa-lo ao invés de fazer o bom e velho `split` e `replace`

```js
var a = 10000.50
var b = a.toLocaleString('pt-BR')
console.log(b)
```

A saída deste código deveria ser `10.000,50`, e não `10.000,5`. Como faz ele não ignorar os centavos? Porque isso são **50** centavos, e não **5**.

Obrigado!

Comment: Ele não sabe que você quer formatação de moeda.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso é configurável com o `minimumFractionDigits` e `maximumFractionDigits`. Se quiseres ter o numero de casa decimais fixo então dá o mesmo número aos dois. Esses valores podem ir de 0 a 20.

```js
var a = 10000.50
var b = a.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 3,
  maximumFractionDigits: 3
})
console.log(b); // 10.000,500
```

Comment: Perfeito Sergio! Sensacional, cara! Obrigado =)

Answer (score 6):

Com a introdução da API `Intl`, o `toLocaleString` pode deixar de ser usado, em favor dessa nova interface, bem mais completa.

Um exemplo:

```js
const number = 1234567.89;

const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'BRL' 
});

const formatted = formatter.format(number);

console.log(formatted); // R$ 1.234.567,89
```

Para saber mais, não deixe de consultar a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat).

Answer (score -3):

```js
var a = 10000.50
var b = a.toLocaleString('pt-br')
console.log(`${b}0`)
```

Comment: É falsa a afirmação de que o código produz a saída `10.000,50`. Isso pode ser facilmente verificado.

Comment: Oi, Augusto, eu sou nova nesse meio, e peço desculpas caso a explicação que eu tenha dado esteja errada, mas eu tentei no console.log e me veio o valor 10.000,50, assim como previsto.

Comment: resultado: https://imgur.com/a/HlSw9Jg