# Como exibir formatar números em javascript. Moeda

Tags: javascript

Possuo um código que pega todos os números presentes em `input type="text" name="qty"` e realiza uma soma.

Se eu tiver dois inputs com valor 30 e com `name="qty"`, o resultado do script
seria 30. Só que preciso que na hora que ele retornar o resultado, os números sejam formatados da seguinte maneira:

```
100.10
1259.59
1300.30
```

Ou seja, antes dos últimos dois dígitos apareça um ponto ou vírgula.

Meu código:

```
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
```

Seria possível?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [toLocaleString R$ brasileiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244083/tolocalestring-r-brasileiro)

Comment: Caro Caio use numeros quebrados ao invés de inteiros.

Answer (score 5):

A pergunta está **muito** confusa. No título você diz que quer formatar "moeda", mas na [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/456436/112052) você formata o número e coloca "Kg" na frente (ou seja, não é um valor monetário).

Além disso, você pega o valor (no seu exemplo, foi 2510) e o resultado é "2.51Kg". Então bastaria dividir por 1000 antes de formatar o valor. Mas na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/456435/112052) (que foi apagada) você diz que se o valor for 3000, você quer que retorne "30.00" (ou seja, divide por 100). Não dá para entender o que você precisa.

De qualquer forma, **talvez** isso lhe ajude. A forma como você fez é muito errada por vários motivos (explico em mais detalhes abaixo). Se quer formatar números, uma alternativa é usar um [`NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat), que inclusive possui suporte à unidades de medida:

```js
let nf = Intl.NumberFormat('en',
                           { style: "unit", unit: "kilogram", unitDisplay: "narrow",
                             minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 3});

function findTotal() {
    let tot = 0;
    for (const input of document.getElementsByName('qty')){
        let value = parseInt(input.value);
        if(! isNaN(value))
            tot += value;
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = nf.format(tot / 1000);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="qty"  value="1255">
<input type="text" name="qty"  value="1255">
<input type="text" name="total" id="total">
<button onclick="findTotal()">teste</button>
```

Usando os valores preenchidos, o total é 2510 (e repare que não precisa chamar [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) duas vezes: chame-o apenas uma vez e use o valor retornado - incluí uma verificação para saber se o valor é um número mesmo, pois se for digitado algo que não é número, ele retorna [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) (mais sobre essas conversões [pode ser visto aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/410229/112052))).

Então eu divido o total por 1000 e formato usando o `NumberFormat`. Usei a unidade "kilogram", que já adiciona o respectivo sufixo ([veja aqui](https://tc39.es/proposal-unified-intl-numberformat/section6/locales-currencies-tz_proposed_out.html#sec-issanctionedsimpleunitidentifier) a lista de todas as unidades suportadas). E eu uso o locale `en`, que usa o ponto como separador das casas decimais, que parece ser o que você precisa.

O resultado é `"2.51kg"`. Se quiser muito que o resultado tenha o "K" maiúsculo, pode usar `replace('k', 'K')` no resultado, ou retirar as opções de unidade de medida e concatenar o "Kg" diretamente. Vale lembrar também que você pode usar as mesmas opções com [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```
(tot / 1000).toLocaleString('en',
                            { style: "unit", unit: "kilogram", unitDisplay: "narrow",
                              minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 3})
.replace('k', 'K'); // se quiser muito que "kg" seja transformado em "Kg"

// ou, se quiser concatenar o "Kg" manualmente
(tot / 1000).toLocaleString('en', { minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 3}) + "Kg";
```

Também coloquei o mínimo e máximo de casas decimais que devem ser impressas, assim se o valor for 2000, ele se torna "2kg", e se for 2100, se torna "2.1kg" e assim por diante. Você pode configurar à vontade, veja na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) todas as opções disponíveis.

<sup>Só não tenho certeza se o "kg" (todo em minúsculas) é padronizado ou varia conforme a implementação de cada *browser*.</sup>

---

Quanto ao seu código:

```
document.getElementById('total').value = tot.toLocaleString('pt-BR')  - 0  + "Kg"
```

Apesar de "funcionar", é uma gambiarra danada (desculpe ser tão direto, mas é). O locale "pt-BR" usa o ponto como separador dos milhares, então o número 2510 se torna a string `"2.510"`. Em seguida, ao subtrair zero, esta string é convertida para número, só que esta conversão não leva em conta o locale "pt-BR" e sim as regras de conversão da linguagem, nas quais o ponto é o separador de casas decimais. Então a string `"2.510"` é interpretada como o número 2,51 - e ao concatená-lo com a string `"Kg"` ele é convertido para string, que também ignora as regras do locale "pt-BR" e usa o ponto como separador decimal, resultando em "2.51Kg".

Não faça isso. Use as ferramentas adequadas para cada tarefa. Primeiro você obtém o valor numérico que quer formatar (seja dividindo por 1000 ou 100, ou qualquer outro cálculo que for necessário), e depois você formata esse valor.

Answer (score 0):

Conseguir chegar perto do que queria ( se alguém precisar ):

```js
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot.toLocaleString('pt-BR')  - 0  + "Kg"   ;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="qty"  value="1255"   >

<input type="text" name="qty"  value="1255"   >



<input type="text" name="total" id="total"   />


<button onclick="findTotal()"   >teste</button>
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.